# C# Request with RestClient to get access_token - don't understand why it IS working

Tags: c#, oauth, access-token, rest-client

I finally managed to recieve a valid (302) response from a RestRequest pasted below, but I don't know why.

Its all about the line with the "Autorisation" and the given Hash:

```
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic xhr5n6xf_Rtguwv_jzr1d3_LTshikn4_0dtesdahNvp1:Kqf2Hs#Wwazl");
```

This line I found in the Internet (including the given Hash) and when I change the Hash or just omitt the line completly, the response turns to a 400 as it was on about 20 other code examples I've tried so far.

**Can anybody explain what is going on here? I would like to omitt the "Authorisation" line including the Hash if possible.**

```cs
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

string url = "https://myurl/oauth2/login?response_type=token";

var client = new RestClient(url);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic xhr5n6xf_Rtguwv_jzr1d3_LTshikn4_0dtesdahNvp1:Kqf2Hs#Wwazl");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "client_id=XXXX&username=YYYY&password=ZZZZ&redirect_uri=", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Why are you surprised that it does work?

Comment: Because I'm using an AUTHORISATION Header and Hash I found in the Internet and can't find any other Info about the Hash - When I change the Hash it doesn't work anymore. I would like to understand why THIS  Hash works

Comment: Can you be super explicit about what you mean by `the hash`?

Comment: What authentication is your server configured to accept?

Comment: Thanks everybody for your questions to help clarify my question.Unfortunately today my request  that had been working yesterday is not working anymore today  and I am unable to reach the administrator of the server. So let me close this question and wait for an answer of the server admin - thanks a lot for your efforts

Comment: @ mjwills: thios is what i ment when speeking of the hash:  "Basic xhr5n6xf_Rtguwv_jzr1d3_LTshikn4_0dtesdahNvp1:Kqf2Hs#Wwazl"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately today I cannot reproduce the successful request from yesterday anymore and I am having problems getting in touch with the server admin.
**So thanks to all for your efforts to help answer my question.**
It seems the best to be patient and wait for an answer from the server admin, so I would like to close this question.